# React Navigation v5: Screen transition animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

I am using `stack navigator` (**React Navigation v5**) in my React Native app. I want to move from screen 1 to screen 2 with **fade transition** which is working absolutely fine with this `code`:

```js
const fadeConfig = ({ current }) => {
    return {
        cardStyle: {
            opacity: current.progress,
        },
    }
};

const Stack = () => {
    const { Navigator, Screen } = Stack;

    return (
        <Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                header: () => null,
            }}
        >
            <Screen
                 name="Screen1"
                 component={Screen1}
            />

            <Screen
                name="Screen2"
                component={Screen2}
                options={{ cardStyleInterpolator: fadeConfig }}
            />
        </Navigator>
    );
};
```

Now, this fade is **linear** across entire screen. But my requirement is to make this fade happen in a **radial** manner, **originating from the point where user taps** with his/her finger. What changes will I have to make in `fadeConfig` in order to achieve the functionality? Thanks.

Comment: A Video or GIF will be very good to understand requirements.

Comment: @Rajan you can check this image [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/shaders/circular-gradients-images/radialgradientmask-large.png). So, let's suppose entire screen is white and when user click, next screen fades in from that point where the user clicked on monkey's face.